# How to set the size of DataGridView VB.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

[Program http://www.repairstatus.org/program.png](http://www.repairstatus.org/program.png)

The DataGridView fetches the data from a MySQL server but it does not fill the entire box in size.

Ideally I would like to manually set the table size to fit the box at least width-wise because the rest will fill up once the database is populated more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the property `AutoSizeColumnsMode` to be `Fill`. That'll ensure your columns stretch to 100% within your DataGridView. The columns will stretch/shrink when you resize your grid (if your grid is anchored to your form).

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Look at the Fill Weights for the Columns.

Specifically, change the `AutoSizeMode` to Fill.

If trying to expand more than one column, adjust the `FillWeight` percentage.